# Which web design site discussed embedding single characters like & using base64?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a well known article site on site design which made an article about embedding just a single character (in this case, '&') from a font to save load times. I believe the site used fixed width, pale colours. Thanks

Comment: One always dream about a search engine that can search on description like this. One that searches _intention_ instead of keyword.

Comment: You can't go too far wrong with [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/)

Answer (score 2):

There was a 24Ways post titled [Spruce it Up](http://24ways.org/2009/spruce-it-up) in 2009 in which the example was ultimately the encoding of a single ampersand.

For cross-reference, there was a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124149/embedding-background-image-data-into-css-as-base64-good-or-bad-practice) about this with some other links and considerations.

@Yi Jian's link doesn't involve encoding at all, just referencing a different font, though is also handy.

Comment: Indeed, that does seem to be the technique the author is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be referring to the [Best Available Ampersand](http://simplebits.com/notebook/2008/08/14/ampersands-2/) technique introduced by [Dan Cederholm](http://simplebits.com/).